# IME_ACTION_DONE seems to destroy the View.OnKeyListener on Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keylistener

I have a `EditText` view on my `RelativeLayout`, and I can capture the soft input keyboard keycode `KEYCODE_ENTER (int 66)`. This is the Key listener:

```
myedittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
  {
    @Override 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
     {
       Log.d("softinput", "key received!");
     }
  });
```

The problem is that the soft keyboard displays the key labeled "Next" and I need it to display "Done". When i (successfully) change the key to "Done" using the API:

```
myedittext.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

The Key listener stops working and i can no longer receive *anything* in the key listener. The  LogCat doesnt show anything. It literally stops working. When i remove the above line of code, everything works again but the key displays "Next".

I was guessing this was clearing some other flag required for it to notify keys, but using EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT works perfect, but the soft key, of course displays "Next".

Anybody knows a workaround for this? or the reasons why this happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an EditText, but your variable is "mytextview". Are you setting the key listener correctly to the **EditText** ?

Comment: That is just the variable holding the view, but it is in fact an EditText view. I modified my post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Change `imeOptions` to action done in XML rather than in code.
Add the following to the `edittext` tag,

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: There is no XML. The EditView is being created at runtime programmatically.